# what data sources are useful for obtaining financial statement data of listed companies NYSE and NASDAQ?

Tags: market-data, finance, historical-data, accounting

Exactly, I need balance sheet, income statement, cash flow statement, stock market, bankruptcy situation, fraud situation and corporate governance data of companies in USA.

Thanks beforehand,

Comment: If you have serious money to spend on data sources, there are several commercial vendors who supply this information in convenient table/DB format.  Common choices include CompuStat, FactSet and Bloomberg.  I have upvoted the answers below citing Quandl and EDGAR as well.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps - the Core US Fundamentals database on Quandl (https://www.quandl.com/data/SF1) covers 6,500+ companies, point-in-time, inc/exc restatements, active/delisted, up to 11 years history, 101 indicators, expanding coverage, daily updates. There's data for balance sheets, income statements, cash flow etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if all companies you are looking for will be listed there but SEC-filing entities must file their reports to EDGAR (Electronic Data Gathering, Analysis, and Retrieval system). This system is available for use by the general public.

https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm